# How to ignore white spaces in emacs evil surround

Tags: emacs, evil

I learned from here http://kana.github.io/config/vim/surround.html that yss should operates on the current line, ignoring leading whitespace. But it always includes the leading whitespace on my machine, which looks bad. I am using emacs 24.3.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should report this to the author of evil-surround. For now, just remember it's a difference in behavior between vim-surround and evil-surround.

Comment: OK, I have created the issue on git hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your own evil-text-object, a line object with spaces trimmed

Here is the complete setup (tested with evil 1.0.9-):

```
(defmacro define-and-bind-text-object (key start-regex end-regex)
  (let ((inner-name (make-symbol "inner-name"))
        (outer-name (make-symbol "outer-name")))
    `(progn
       (evil-define-text-object ,inner-name (count &optional beg end type)
         (evil-regexp-range count beg end type ,start-regex ,end-regex t))
       (evil-define-text-object ,outer-name (count &optional beg end type)
         (evil-regexp-range count beg end type ,start-regex ,end-regex nil))
       (define-key evil-inner-text-objects-map ,key (quote ,inner-name))
       (define-key evil-outer-text-objects-map ,key (quote ,outer-name)))))

;; trimmed line
(define-and-bind-text-object "l" "^ *" " *$")
```

Above code does not work on latest dev version, I already notified the developer. https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/478/new-text-object-created-from-regex-hang

Comment: Thank you sir. I find smartparens also quite handy when I want to quote some text.